# How to limit text length of a TextSpan widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter. How to limit text when I use `TextSpan` widget?

My code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        lastPlayedGame.imagePath,
                        height: 60,
                        width: 45,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      left: 8,
                      right: 8,
                      top: 0,
                      bottom: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.play_arrow,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                  child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(children: [
                      TextSpan(text: lastPlayedGame.name, style: headingTwoTextStyle,),
                      TextSpan(text: '\n'),
                      TextSpan(text: "${lastPlayedGame.hoursPlayed} hours played", style: bodyTextStyle),
                    ]),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GameProgressWidget(screenWidth: screenWidth, gameProgress: gameProgress),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When run on my Android device, I get an error:

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 15 pixels on the right.

[image]

How to limit text length? Maybe check if text is maximum of screen, will show `Assasin's Creed...` (with dots maybe?)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to use your [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) Widget inside a [Row](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) and prevent the overflow with an ellipsis, you first have to wrap it inside a [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html). The `Flexible` shows the `Row` that the `RichText` can be shrinked.

After wrapping the `RichText` inside a `Flexible`, simply add `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` to your `RichText`. Here a minimal example with a `RichText` inside an `Flexible` inside a `Row`.

[image: Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          color: Colors.lime,
          width: 200.0,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: RichText(
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  strutStyle: StrutStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                  text: TextSpan(
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      text: 'A very long text :)'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 100.0,
                color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              )
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

You can also try this if you want to customize it:

```
Text(
  _name.length > 10 ? _name.substring(0, 10)+'...' : _name,
   style: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.white,
     fontSize: 22,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
   ),
 ),
```

It displays the `ellipsis` if the **length of the text is more than 10**.

Comment: Cool , thats what i wanted

Answer (score 21):

There's no need of using **RichText**. Just add your **Text** a parameter of
`overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` and the Wrap the Text widget with `Flexible`

**Example**:

```
 Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.grey),
              Flexible(
                  child: Text(propertyModel.propertyAddress, style: AppTextStyle.headerSmall2(context),
                 overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 7):

Try to set overflow property:

```
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
```

Comment: Hi @Munjunath I try but still same output

Comment: This alone won't work inside a `Row`. @Bertho Joris you can have a look at my answer, I've added the missing information.

Answer (score -3):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            color: Colors.lime,
            height: 200,
            width: 200.0,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: Text("Mais de 200 países criaram restrições à entrada de brasileiros por conta da nossa gestão da pandemia",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please add some notes or comment about how your answer help to solve OP's problem, also as I see your solution do not cover different screen sizes...

Answer (score -4):

**Adding more** to the **above-selected answer**. if you want to show the dots (...) after a certain number of lines you can use the `maxLines` option.

Example:

```
....
....

Flexible(
    child: RichText(
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    maxLines: 2, // this will show dots(...) after 2 lines
    strutStyle: StrutStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
    text: TextSpan(
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
             text: 'A very long text :)'
          ),
       ),
    ),

.....
.....
```

Comment: It's for line limit not for text limit